# Overriding Order class in sylius throwing exception 'sylius_order' already exists

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to add a new field to order table. But overrding is throwing error like table already exist. I tried to follow https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/3997 issue. but no luck.

My Entity

```
   <?php

namespace Goldco\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\Order as BaseOrder;//Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Order as BaseOrder;
use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\OrderItemUnitInterface;

/**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_order")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order extends BaseOrder
{


    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity_decimal", type="decimal", precision=12, scale=4, nullable=true, options={"comment"="decimal quantity"})
     */
    private $quantityDecimal;



}
```

Config file :

```
sylius_order:
    resources:
        order_item:
            classes:
                model: Goldco\Entity\SyliusOrderItem
                controller : Goldco\Controller\App\OrderItemController
        order:
            classes:
                model: Goldco\Entity\Order
                controller: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\OrderController
                repository: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\OrderRepository
```

And orm.yml

```
Goldco\Entity\Order:
    type: entity
    table: sylius_order
    fields:
        quantityDecimal:
            type: decimal
            nullable: true
            precision: 12
            scale: 4
            options:
                comment: 'decimal quantity'
            column: quantity_decimal
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

On executing orm command I'm getting error like:

```
 The table with name 'eco_latest.sylius_order' already exists.
```

anything missing here in config?

Edit :

```
 $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE SyliusOrder (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, number VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, notes LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, checkout_completed_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, items_total INT NOT NULL, adjustments_total INT NOT NULL, total INT NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, currency_code VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, locale_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, checkout_state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, payment_state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, shipping_state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, token_value VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, customer_ip VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, invoice_no VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, invoice_file_path VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_3458A6D996901F54 (number), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
```

And `syliusorder` table was created in my DB. I'm not sure whether any settings need to be done to fix that.

Comment: try to remove line `@ORM\Table(name="sylius_order")`

Comment: If I remove that new SyliusOrder table will be created. I want to edit sylius_order

Comment: Did you really tried it? Doctrine by default saves new tables in snake_case naming

Comment: @Dr.X: yes, migration script added in question. Please refer that

Answer (score 1):

The customized class has to be a mapped superclass.
Use the following annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_order")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

On orm.yml, change the type from `entity` to `mappedSuperclass`

`Goldco\Entity\Order:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    table: sylius_order
    ...`